# Vue3 IntelliJ autosuggestion of property names in camelCase

Tags: intellij-idea, vuejs3, autosuggest

How can I set up autocompletion in IntelliJ so that in Vue files the names of properties in components in templates are suggested in camelCase not a kebab-case

I can't find any settings in IntelliJ, and there is something like this in VSC